# Drupal GraphQL logic for Resolver for a field with multiple values

Tags: reactjs, graphql, drupal-8, react-apollo

My first Drupal headless project with GraphQL and I am struggling with the logic behind the resolvers.

There is a content type "project" with a field "field_project_description". The field can store multiple values.

This is part of my schema:

```
type Project {
  id: Int!
  project_title: String!
  project_description: [ProjectDescription]
}

type ProjectDescription {
  value: String
}
```

And this is how the one part of the corresponding resolver looks:

```
    $registry->addFieldResolver('ProjectDescription', 'value',
      $builder->produce('property_path')
        ->map('type', $builder->fromValue('entity:node'))
        ->map('value', $builder->fromParent())
        ->map('path', $builder->fromValue('field_project_project_desc.value'))
    );
```

But as far as I understand there has to be another resolver like

`$registry->addFieldResolver('Project', 'project_description',`

And I can't figure out, what this resolver has to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem myself. The answer is very simple actually.

You don't need a second resolver. Just one resolver with an additional PHP function, which flattens the arrays to the strings is enough. This is what the code looks like now.

The schema:

```
type Project {
  id: Int!
  project_title: String!
  project_description: [String]
}
```

And the resolver:

```
$registry->addFieldResolver('Project', 'project_description',
  $builder->compose(
    $builder->produce('property_path')
      ->map('type', $builder->fromValue('entity:node'))
      ->map('value', $builder->fromParent())
      ->map('path', $builder->fromValue('field_project_project_desc')),
    $builder->callback(function ($entity) {
      $list = [];
      foreach($entity as $item){
        array_push($list, $item['value']);
      }
      return $list;
    })
  )
);
```

I hope I can help someone else with this.